# Как убрать невидимую область вокруг DialogFragment?

Tags: android, dialogfragment

Я сделал `DialogFragment` с использованием своего лейаута, который по нажатию за его пределами закрывается. Но! Эти пределы идут не четко по грани моего диалога. Для того, что бы диалог закрылся, нужно кликнуть примерно на сантиметр от его границы. Это свойство замечено в большинстве диалогов, даже стандартных. Такое чувство, что у него есть какой то `padding`(в разметке `padding` нет).

Как сделать что бы диалог более чувствительно реагировал и закрывался при нажатие прям за его границей?

Comment: Может попробовать элементы диалога поместить в какой нибудь контейнер  и на этот контейнер уже повешать onClickLisner, если id не контейнера, тогда вызвать dialog.cansel

Comment: В конечном итоге пришлось использовать PopupWindow